# Error when setting Header in all requests - Cypress (JS)

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, automated-tests, cypress

I have the following question. Could you help me?

I want to set custom header in all requests in my automated tests: "Content-Type" and "accept".

How can i get?

I tried that way but without success...

> **File commands.js**

```
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'makeRequest',
  ({ headers }) => {
    cy.request({
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
      }
  }
```

> **File index.js**

```
beforeEach(() => {
  cy.makeRequest();
  });
```

> **Error below:**
>
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'headers' of 'undefined' as it
> is undefined.
> Because this error occurred during a `before each` hook we are skipping all of the remaining tests.

If anyone can help, it will be appreciated!!!
If there is any other way to do what I want, let me know too!!
thanks in advance

**> After adjusting according to suggestion...**

> commands.js file

```
    Cypress.Commands.add(
  'makeRequest',
  (headers = {}) => {
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'applicationdsd/json',
      ...headers
    }
    cy.request({
      headers
    })
  }
)
```

> index.js file

```
beforeEach(() => {
cy.makeRequest({'accept': 'text/html'});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably see from the error message that passing nothing here `cy.makeRequest()` gives a problem here `({ headers }) => {`, since you are not passing anything in.

You can get rid of the brackets, for example this will not error

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'makeRequest',
  (headers) => {
    cy.request({
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
      }
    })
  }
})

cy.makeRequest();
```

but you aren't using the `headers` parameter.

---

If you want to add extra `headers` or perform one-time over-ride, you need this

```js
Cypress.Commands.add(
  'makeRequest',
  (url, headers = {}) => {           
    
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'accept': 'application/json',
      ...headers                // add or over-ride headers from parameter
    }

    cy.request({
      url, 
      headers
    })
  }
})

cy.makeRequest(myUrl, {'accept': 'text/html'});  // change this header one time only
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the help!

I did what you suggested but now I get another error: CypressError: `cy.request()` requires a `url`. You did not provide a `url`.

Could you help me?

Comment: Lola Ichingbola, could you help me?!

Comment: I want to send my url only in the test file...

Comment: Indeed, you can pass as many parameters as you want -  see above for example.

Comment: Lola, I added at the end of the description another line with my adjusted code and the error, ok?

If you can help, thank you.

I keep getting the same error...

Comment: Lola, i added from the subtitle "> After adjusting according to suggestion..."
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Weird, I definitely don't get the error you mentioned!

Comment: Try using a different name for the parameter, for example `headerOptions`.